# Function to build an unknown number of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

What is the best solution for creating the necessary number of dictionaries based on the number of lists that have a value matching a specified value? And how do I specify an intuitive name for the dictionaries?

I made a (rookie) mistake. I hard-coded a predefined set of dictionaries ignoring potential future cases.

**My snippet:**

```
primarytuesday = {}
secondarytuesday = {}
primarythursday = {}
secondarythursday = {}
coaches = [["4/27/1976", "Person One", "Site 1"], ["4/27/1976", "Person Two", "Site 1"],
       ["4/29/1976", "Person Three", "Site 1"], ["4/29/1976", "Person Four", "Site 1"]]


def sort_coaches(date, primary, secondary):
    for eachsession in coaches:
        if eachsession[0] == date:
            if eachsession[2] in primary:
                secondary[eachsession[2]] = eachsession[1]
            else:
                primary[eachsession[2]] = eachsession[1]


sort_coaches("4/27/1976", primarytuesday, secondarytuesday)
sort_coaches("4/29/1976", primarythursday, secondarythursday)
```

**Output** (working as intended):

1. `primarytuesday == {'Site 1': 'Person One'}`
2. `secondarytuesday == {'Site 1': 'Person Two'}`
3. `primarythursday == {'Site 1': 'Person Three'}`
4. `secondarythursday == {'Site 1': 'Person Four'}`

**Issue:** The issue comes if a third value for a particular day is added to the list as in...

```
coaches = [["4/27/1976", "Person One", "Site 1"], ["4/27/1976", "Person Two", "Site 1"], ["4/27/1976", "Person Three", "Site 1"]
           ["4/29/1976", "Person Four", "Site 1"], ["4/29/1976", "Person Five", "Site 1"]]
```

The output changes the value in secondarytuesday to the third individual and gets rid of the second individual completely. Makes sense, but not what is intended.

My first thought is to scrap the entire code and create a nested function for each list within the list. This would probably require some use of zip, but I'm not completely sure.

As an aside: I'm sure there are more efficient ways as opposed to iterating over the entire list and comparing `eachsession[0]` to date within the for loop, but let that serve as an example of where I am as a coder.

Comment: To collect an unknown number of items, you would use a `list`. To add a new item to an existing list, you would use the `append` method.

Comment: Maybe you should read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists again?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! Is your suggestion to append each list of the list to a new list and then create the dictionaries based on len(newlist)? I'm missing how this would satisfy the requirement of creating the unique dictionaries.

Comment: `unknown_amount_of_dicts = []` ... `for key in range(42): unknown_amount_of_dicts.append( {key:key**2} )` - presto ... lots of dicts. stored in a list. You dont name them - you access them by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use lists at the output of your function instead of individual variables.  This will allow you to have any number of primary, secondary, tertiary, ... entries that you can manipulate using indexes within a day.

In fact, you can convert the whole thing to a master dictionary indexed on dates in one pass and then use the dictionary:

```
coaches = [["4/27/1976", "Person One", "Site 1"], ["4/27/1976", "Person Two", "Site 1"], ["4/27/1976", "Person Three", "Site 1"],
           ["4/29/1976", "Person Four", "Site 1"], ["4/29/1976", "Person Five", "Site 1"]]

sortedCoaches = dict()
for date,person,site in coaches:
    day = sortedCoaches.setdefault(date,list())
    d   = next((d for d in day if site not in d),dict())
    if not d: day.append(d)                    
    d[site] = person


dayInfo = sortedCoaches["4/27/1976"]
[{'Site 1': 'Person One'}, {'Site 1': 'Person Two'}, {'Site 1': 'Person Three'}]


dayInfo = sortedCoaches["4/29/1976"]
[{'Site 1': 'Person Four'}, {'Site 1': 'Person Five'}]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Can you elaborate on the line "if not d:"? Is this saying if the current day is not the same as the next day, add it as a new list?

Comment: `if not d:` will return true if the `d` dictionary is empty.  On the previous line `next(...,dict())` will either find an existing dictionary to insert the site into or it will place a new empty dictionary in `d`.  So, if `d` is empty we know all entries for the day contain the site so the new empty dictionary must be added to the list and used for the site.

Comment: Oh brilliant. So dayInfo[0] will return all primary coaches for each site, dayInfo[1] secondary, and so on. Correct?